# Cassandra directory setup of replica datacenter

Tags: cassandra, installation

I have a Cassandra cluster and plan to add a new datacenter to replicate data. There will be no write on this node, only reads.

My questions are:

- in this case is it still recommended to have separate drives for commit log and data?
- if I know, that my cluster will receive data only by hints (and lots of them) should I create a separate disk for the hints? I did not find any mention of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> in this case is it still recommended to have separate drives for commit log and data?

So the whole idea of putting your commitlog on a separate mount point, goes back to spinning disks being a chokepoint for I/O.  If you have your cluster/nodes backed by SSDs, you shouldn't need to do that.

> if I know, that my cluster will receive data only by hints (and lots of them) should I create a separate disk for the hints?

Hints only build up when a node is down.  When your writes happen, the Snitch handles propagation of all of the required replicas.  So no, I wouldn't worry about putting your hints dir on a separate mount point, either.